# How can I use a variable amongst many projects?

Tags: python, automated-tests

**Here is my problem:**

The same string variable is referenced in many GitHub repositories which me & my colleagues manage.
If the variable is defined in each repository and the value of the variable changes, we have to go into each repository and change the variable. This is time-consuming.

Specifically, we are testers & one of the variables might be an xpath.

**Solutions:**

It's as if we want a website which stores the variables.

1. our code should read from the website & bring down the value of the variable.
2. me & my colleagues can manually edit the value of these variables on the website.

The words 'Database', 'API' & 'JSON' come to mind.

Flask & RapidAPI (as described in this [tutorial](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-build-an-api-in-python/)) look promising but I'm worried they won't satisfy requirement 2.

Note: we use Python (& Selenium).

Comment: would this value typically be kept in sync across all the repositories? or would different people be using different values at the same time? How often are the values being changed?  is this a standard part of your testing workflow, or is this something that gets changed between versions of the software under test?

Answer (score 0):

Your question really asks (at least) two distinct questions: 1) How to have code in multiple Github repositories refer to a single definition of a particular variable that has its value set statically in the code (a constant)?, and 2) How to have code get a value from an external source or compute or maintain a value dynamically?

The answer to the second question has literally hundreds of possible answers.

To answer the first question, you could define the variable in one place (one package) in your code and then have the code in other repos that need to refer to that variable be dependent on the package that defines the variable.  This amounts to defining a constant in one package that other modules can reference.  An example of this would be Python's "re" module and its definition of the IGNORECASE constant:

```
import re
...
re.compile("some pattern", re.IGNORECASE)
```

so in your case, code that referenced the value in question might look something like:

```
import our_shared_module:
...
foo = our_shared_module.SOME_SHARED_STRING_VALUE
```

The best answer to your question will depend on parameters you haven't specified.  How would you prefer that this value be set?  Do you want to change it in code that lives in a GitHub repo, or would you rather go to a web UI and set it there?  When would you like changing the value of the variable to take affect?  Should running code be able to see the variable change and alter its behavior, or do you only want new executions to see the change?  Do you build your code into separate execution packages containing copies of the modules in your repos, or do you reference the source code files directly whenever you run your code?  There are a lot of variables you haven't defined that will determine your best course of action.